# Golang Reflection: Inspect a struct type definition to extract its properties without initialization

Tags: go

If I have the following declaration

```
type Foo struct {
   bar string
}
```

Can I use reflection to inspect the properties on the declaration without initialising it?

```
keys := reflect.something(Foo)

for _, key := range keys {
    fmt.Println(key) // "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [reflect.TypeOf](https://godoc.org/reflect#TypeOf) to get the reflect.Type for `Foo`.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Foo{})
```

If you don't want to create a value of the type, then get the pointer type and "dereference" that type.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*Foo)(nil)).Elem()
```

The expression `(*Foo)(nil)` returns a nil pointer to the type. The [Type.Elem](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Elem) method returns the pointed to type.

Iterate through the fields on the type. [Type.NumField](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.NumField) returns the number of fields on the type.  [Type.Field](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Field) returns a [StructField](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructField) by field index.

```
for i := 0; i < t.NumField; i++ {
    fmt.Println(t.Field(i).Name)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4ROSNZwEGlS).